# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22] When adding quiz content

Tags: 7, features, quiz

I am trying to implement the quiz module on a new website and it's throwing the following error when attempting to add content > quiz. I believe the code I have was part of a feature I was trying to migrate over from a different website so I could retain the functionality involved with it, but it's proven to be less than compatible. (Going from Drupal Commons 7.50 to Plain Drupal with a demo theme built in 7.54).

Can someone interpret this error and point me in the right direction as to what the missing piece of the puzzle is here?

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.allow_change_blank' in 'field list': SELECT base.qnp_id
>   AS qnp_id,  base.vid 
>       AS vid, base.nid AS nid, base.uid AS uid, base.number_of_random_questions AS 
>       number_of_random_questions, base.max_score_for_random AS max_score_for_random, 
>       base.pass_rate AS pass_rate, base.summary_pass AS summary_pass, 
>       base.summary_pass_format AS summary_pass_format, base.summary_default AS 
>       summary_default, base.summary_default_format AS summary_default_format, 
>       base.randomization AS randomization, base.backwards_navigation AS 
>       backwards_navigation, base.keep_results AS keep_results, base.repeat_until_correct 
>       AS repeat_until_correct, base.quiz_open AS quiz_open, base.quiz_close AS 
>       quiz_close, base.takes AS takes, base.show_attempt_stats AS show_attempt_stats, 
>       base.time_limit AS time_limit, base.quiz_always AS quiz_always, base.time_left AS 
>       time_left, base.max_score AS max_score, base.allow_skipping AS allow_skipping, 
>       base.allow_resume AS allow_resume, base.allow_jumping AS allow_jumping, 
>       base.allow_change AS allow_change, base.allow_change_blank AS allow_change_blank, 
>       base.build_on_last AS build_on_last, base.show_passed AS show_passed, 
>       base.mark_doubtful AS mark_doubtful, base.review_options AS review_options, 
>       base.result_type AS result_type FROM {quiz_node_properties} base WHERE (base.vid 
>       IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 351 ) 
>       in EntityAPIController->query() (line 187 of 
>       /Applications/AMPPS/www/example/docroot/profiles/cms/modules/contrib/entity/inc
>       ludes/entity.controller.inc).

Here is how the process went:

- I implemented an online training feature from our current website for the new one
- It included syllabus and quiz content types, neither of which worked until I installed the Title module
- Once Title was installed, I received a new error only when trying to create content type quiz:

> EntityFieldQueryException: Unknown field: title_field in
>   EntityFieldQuery->fieldOrderBy() (line 954 of
>   /var/www/html/example/docroot/includes/entity.inc).

- I updated the quiz from 7.x-5.0-alpha4+77-dev to 7.x-5.1 and all seemed well
- I removed a quiz field `field_syllabus_ref` and recreated it a different way, to reference the title of the syllabus page in the quiz.
- Now I get the error below unless the module is uninstalled. When it is uninstalled, I am still able to add quiz content but I get a different error instead after saving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was somehow related to the UUID module, which couldn't be disabled without derailing the entire website. Here's how I fixed it.

- uninstalled the feature that held the affected quiz module

  `drush pm-disable <my_feature>
  drush pm-uninstall <my_feature>`
- uninstalled the quiz module and all the modules dependent on it:

  `drush pm-disable quiz
  drush pm-uninstall quiz`
- moved the quiz module files to my temp backup outside the drupal root:

`mv sites/all/modules/contrib/quiz ../<temp_backups>/quiz`

- downloaded the quiz module fresh and reenabled it and all the dependent modules and reenabled the feature that contained it:

`drush dl quiz`

`drush en quiz`

That took care of this particular error.

**Please note:** I did not yet have any quiz data or content set up; this guideline is only safe for a dev environment. I have not tested it with any actual content or user data.